# Duplicate rows and include a new column with alternating value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that relates US states to their population in millions:

```
State      | Pop
-----------+-------
California | 39 M
Texas      | 29 M
Florida    | 21 M
New York   | 19 M
Ohio       | 11 M
```

I need to use this table to generate a new table that has an 'a' and 'b' row for each of the original rows, i.e., looks like this:

```
State      | Pop  | Switch
-----------+------+-------
California | 39 M |   a
California | 39 M |   b
Texas      | 29 M |   a
Texas      | 29 M |   b
Florida    | 21 M |   a
Florida    | 21 M |   b
New York   | 19 M |   a
New York   | 19 M |   b
Ohio       | 11 M |   a
Ohio       | 11 M |   b
```

I am not allowed to alter the original table.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `cross join`, here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=536d94c58100474032e950cf661d2f96).

```
select 
  *
from myTable
cross join (values ('a'), ('b')) as val (switch)
```

output:

```
state      | pop  | switch
-----------+------+-------
California | 39 M |   a
California | 39 M |   b
Texas      | 29 M |   a
Texas      | 29 M |   b
Florida    | 21 M |   a
Florida    | 21 M |   b
New York   | 19 M |   a
New York   | 19 M |   b
Ohio       | 11 M |   a
Ohio       | 11 M |   b
```

Comment: Both yours and Conetfun's solutions worked, but yours was more concise. Thanks for the help. Marked as solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you desired output in alternate order of switch

```
select state, pop, switch
from (
select state, pop, 'a' as switch
from table
union all
select state, pop, 'b' as switch
from table
)x
order by state, pop, switch;
```

Comment: This will work not only in SQL Server but in all databases that are ANSII compatible.

Comment: ANSI compatible, sure, but it should be noted that comes at a cost: this will scan `table` twice (whereas the cross join solution only has to scan once).